# Preflight Request fails CORS (does not have HTTP Request OK status ) when response code isn't hardcoded

Tags: php, cors, backend

I am using a simple PHP backend and Angular frontend. I was having trouble with CORS. I have set proper headers and still faced CORS block. I tried a lot of things and noticed the following.

Since I expected a lot of PHP files I wanted uniformity among the responses. So, I created a PHP file called httpHelper.php and added a function that would set headers, response status code, and return the response.

The following is the httpHelper.php

```
<?php

function json_response($code = 200, $message = null)
{
    header_remove();
    http_response_code($code);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    
    return "{ \"detail\":". $message."}";
}
```

The call to this function would be made from another PHP file that would be like,

```
echo json_response(200, json_encode(FALSE));
```

I was faced with the CORS block..

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8080/checkFeedbackStatus.php' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
> HTTP ok status.

But when the same httpHelper.php was coded with a constant status code, I have no issue.

```
<?php

function json_response($code = 200, $message = null)
{
    header_remove();
    http_response_code(200);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    
    return "{ \"detail\":". $message."}";
}
```

I would like to know what I am missing, where things are getting messed up.

By the way, The request type was HTTP POST

Comment: The request type is not POST, it is OPTIONS because the error tells you it is the preflight request. It also tells you that ti "doesn't have an ok status" so the first thing to do is to find out what kind of status is does have. How you solve a Forbidden error is very different to how you solve an Internal Server Error. Look in the network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, so that was the issue. I was sending 405 response code for all request methods except post. Which included Options. I didn't know pre-flight was of options type. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

It will not work until you use actual domain, it is currently against the CORS headers.
there may be several ways to make it work but i know only 2 of them.

1. Using Proxy in Xampp
2. Using Ngrok, this will provide you public domain to loopback on localhost.

If you are using xampp, you can edit **httpd.conf** and add a proxy at the end of the file and restart the **apache** service

```
ProxyPass /checkStatus http://localhost:8080/checkFeedbackStatus.php
ProxyPassReverse /checkStatus http://localhost:8080/checkFeedbackStatus.php
```

For Ngrok you can read the docs [here](https://ngrok.com/docs#getting-started-expose)
Once you setup ngrok, you can use any port to use ngrok as a public domain

```
ngrok http 8080
```